# ElasticSearch Java API nested query with inner_hits error

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

i have problem with ElasticSearch Java API. I use version 5.1.2.

I will now describe code pasted below. I need to optimize search mechanism by limiting inner_hits only to object id. I used InnerHitBuilder with .setFetchSourceContext(FetchSourceContext.DO_NOT_FETCH_SOURCE) and .addDocValueField("item.id"). Query being generated has error - there is "ignore_unmapped" attribute inside "inner_hits" node.

```
..."inner_hits": {
    "name": "itemTerms",
    "ignore_unmapped": false,
    "from": 0,
    "size": 2147483647,
    "version": false,
    "explain": false,
    "track_scores": false,
    "_source": false,
    "docvalue_fields": ["item.id"]
}...
```

Executing such query results with error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "[inner_hits] unknown field [ignore_unmapped], parser not found"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "[inner_hits] unknown field [ignore_unmapped], parser not found"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

When i manually remove that attribute from query, everything runs smoothly.

```
protected BoolQueryBuilder itemTermQuery(FileTerms terms, boolean withInners) {

    BoolQueryBuilder termsQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    for (String term : FileTerms.terms()) {

        if (terms.term(term).isEmpty())
            continue;

        Set<String> fns = terms.term(term).stream().
                map(x -> x.getTerm())
                .filter(y -> !y.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if (!fns.isEmpty())
            termsQuery = termsQuery.must(
                    QueryBuilders.termsQuery("item.terms." + term + ".term", fns));
    }

    QueryBuilder query = terms.notEmpty() ? termsQuery : QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();

    TermsQueryBuilder discontinuedQuery = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("item.terms." + FileTerms.Terms.USAGE_IS + ".term",
            new FileTerm("Discontinued", "", "", "", "").getTerm());
    FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.FilterFunctionBuilder[] functionBuilders = {
            new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.FilterFunctionBuilder(query, ScoreFunctionBuilders.weightFactorFunction(1)),
            new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.FilterFunctionBuilder(discontinuedQuery, ScoreFunctionBuilders.weightFactorFunction(-1000))
    };
    FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionScoreQuery = functionScoreQuery(functionBuilders);
    NestedQueryBuilder nested = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("item", functionScoreQuery.query(), ScoreMode.None);

    if (withInners) nested = nested.innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder()
            .setFetchSourceContext(FetchSourceContext.DO_NOT_FETCH_SOURCE)
            .addDocValueField("item.id")
            .setSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .setName("itemTerms"));

    return QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(nested);
}
```

How to build query without that unnecessary attribute inside "inner_hits" node?

EDIT:
I use 5.1.2 library and 5.1.2 elastic server.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
</dependency>

  "version": {
    "number": "5.1.2",
    "build_hash": "c8c4c16",
    "build_date": "2017-01-11T20:18:39.146Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "6.3.0"
  },
```

Comment: Check if your Elasticsearch version is the same as Java ES client version

Comment: @TarasKohut i edited question with version informations

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on the new project. There is no "ignore_unmapped" field in the generated query:
"inner_hits" : {
            "name" : "itemTerms",
            "from" : 0,
            "size" : 2147483647,
            "version" : false,
            "explain" : false,
            "track_scores" : false,
            "_source" : false,
            "docvalue_fields" : [
              "item.id"
            ]
          }

Probably you have some dependency conflicts. Try to reproduce it on clean project.